# Extensions of $F$-isocrystals

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, crystals

Let $X$ be a smooth affine scheme over $k$, a finite field. Let $W(k)$ denote the Witt ring, and $K$ its fraction field. Fix a smooth lift of $X$ to $K$ and denote it by $X_K$.

Let $b\in X(k)$ denote a point, and let $F\text{-Isoc}(X)$ denote the category of $F$-isocrystals on $X$. The functoriality of $F\text{-Isoc}$ induces a tensor functor $b^*: F\text{-Isoc}(X)\longrightarrow \text{M}^{\phi}$, of $\phi$-modules defined over $K$.

Since $b^*$ is a tensor functor, it is exact, which induces a homomorphism $\text{Ext}_1(\mathcal{E}_1,\mathcal{E}_2)\longrightarrow \text{Ext}_1(b^*\mathcal{E}_1,b^*\mathcal{E}_2)$, where $\mathcal{E}_i\in F\text{-Isoc(X)}$, the first extension group is of $F$-isocrystals and the second extension group is of $\phi$-modules.

My question is: is this an isomorphism.

Comment: No, because one can easily find examples where the dimension of the right-hand Ext is NOT independent of b.

Comment: Great point, is this the only obstruction however? I somehow think it may be possible to deduce this statement in case $\text{Ext}_1(\mathcal{E}_1,\mathcal{E}_2)$ is a locally constant sheaf for the Zariski topology (assuming $X$ is irreducible), which might hold if the Newton polygon of $\mathcal{E}_1$ and $\mathcal{E}_2$ are constant on $X$.